# Reverse the color order on a calendarHeatMap

Tags: r, heatmap

I would like to know how to reverse the color of this [calendarHeatmap](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/iClick/versions/1.4/topics/calendarHeat) so that white = 0 and the darkest blue = 120

```
calendarHeat(myd$date1, myd$heatvar, varname="VAR name", ncolors=5,color="w2b" )
```

[image]

source

```
st <- as.Date("2010-2-17")
en <- as.Date("2013-4-7")
datell <- seq(st, en, "1 day")
myd <- data.frame (date1 = datell, heatvar = rnorm (length (datell), 50, 20))


require(lattice)
require(chron)
require(grid)

calendarHeat(myd$date1, myd$heatvar, varname="VAR name", ncolors=5, color="w2b")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about we copy the source code of the `calendarHeat` function and then reverse the `w2b` color palette, something like:

```
require(lattice)
require(chron)
require(grid)

# Grab the source code
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iascchen/VisHealth/master/R/calendarHeat.R")

# Create a copy of the heatmap function
calendarHeat2 <- calendarHeat

# Reverse the color palette for the copied function
body(calendarHeat2)[[23]] <- substitute(w2b <- rev(c("#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#BDC9E1", "#F1EEF6")))

# Plot!
calendarHeat2(myd$date1, myd$heatvar, varname="VAR name", ncolors=5, color="w2b")
```

[image]

Data:

```
st <- as.Date("2010-2-17")
en <- as.Date("2013-4-7")
datell <- seq(st, en, "1 day")
myd <- data.frame (date1 = datell, heatvar = rnorm(length(datell), 50, 20))
```